# PHP - Selecting random strings/variables to echo from a file

Tags: php, variables, echo, explode

what I am trying to achieve here is echoing a list of 5 links, the links are created from keywords within a file being comma seperated (keyword1, keyword2). The file contains 20 keywords and I'm wanting to randomly grab 5 to display on each page load.

The issue I am currently experiencing is that all the keywords are being echoed out rather than just the 5. This is what I have:

```
<?php

$keywords=file_get_contents("keywordlist.php");

$keyword_list = explode("\n",$keywords);
shuffle($keyword_list);

$display = 5;

if((count($keyword_list) - 1) > ($display - 1))
    {
        $show = $display - 1;
        }
else
    {
        $show = count($keyword_list) - 1;
        }

        for ($i=0; $i<=$show; $i++)
            {
                $page_name = $keyword_list[$i];
                $clean_list = str_replace(" ","-",$page_name);
                $output .= '<a href="/'.$clean_list.'">'.$page_name.'</a>, ';
                }

echo $output;

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you :)

Comment: what's not working or what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$keywords = explode(",", file_get_contents("keywordlist.php"));
shuffle($keywords);
$links = array();
foreach (array_slice($keywords, 0, 5) as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    $slug = str_replace(" ", "-", $word);
    $links[] = '<a href="/' . $slug . '">' . $word . '</a>';
}
echo join(',', $links);
```

Comment: Just going over this and it appears to be much more friendly than my previous code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> within a file being comma seperated

then in your code you

```
$keyword_list = explode("\n",$keywords);
```

So if your keywords are separated by commas, change your code to

```
$keyword_list = explode(",",$keywords);
```

otherwise change your input file.

Comment: lol so simple can't believe I didn't notice. Thank you haha :)